# Building TBB on Windows using MingW & Cmake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, tbb

Hey I'm trying to build TBB on my Windows computer using MinGW & CMake. (gcc,,g++, ..)
I have already tried using the premade binaries but I keep getting undefined reference issues.
My cmake for the project I'm trying to import it in looks as following:

`find_package(TBB REQUIRED tbb)`

`target_link_libraries(projectName PRIVATE ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})`

I use the source code of https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/releases/tag/v2021.3.0 (latest)

and I make a build dir and cd into it and execute:

`cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

followed by:
`cmake --build .` 
also tried:
`mingw32-make`
Both result into

````
[  1%] Building CXX object src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/address_waiter.cpp.obj
In file included from c:\users\refactor\downloads\onetbb-2021.3.0\onetbb-2021.3.0\include\oneapi\tbb\detail\_utils.h:26,
                 from C:\Users\Refactor\Downloads\oneTBB-2021.3.0\oneTBB-2021.3.0\src\tbb\address_waiter.cpp:17:
c:\users\refactor\downloads\onetbb-2021.3.0\onetbb-2021.3.0\include\oneapi\tbb\detail\_machine.h:67: error: ignoring '#pragma intrinsic ' [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
   67 | #pragma intrinsic(_mm_mfence)
      |
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
cc1plus.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src\tbb\CMakeFiles\tbb.dir\build.make:76: src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/address_waiter.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:454: src/tbb/CMakeFiles/tbb.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:165: all] Error 2```
````

Comment: The error is same as in [that bugreport](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/387), which is currently opened.

Comment: The MinGW support (https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/pull/351) was merged to oneTBB, can you please try again?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments there are issues building with MinGW with the latest versions of TBB.

The last version of TBB I was able to build was [2020.0](https://github.com/intel/tbb/archive/v2020.0.tar.gz) using this command (replace `intel64` with `ia32` for 32-bit):

```sh
mingw32-make compiler=gcc arch=intel64 runtime=mingw tbb tbbmalloc CPLUS="g++ -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc"
```